# Storing data with help of localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am storing `localstorage` data in an array. My code is:

```
 var a;
//is anything in localstorage?
if (localStorage.getItem('session') === null) {
    a = [];
} else {
     // Parse the serialized data back into an array of objects
     a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));
 }
 // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the array
 a.push(data);
  document.write(a + "<br>")
 // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
 localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
```

where `data`is:

```
var data = {name: "abc", place: "xyz"}
```

On every page refresh, my data is getting multiplied like this:

```
[{name: "abc", place: "xyz"}, {name: "abc", place: "xyz"}, {name: "abc", place: "xyz"}, {name: "abc", place: "xyz"}]
```

I want to store data only if value of `data` changes means instead of `{name: "abc", place: "xyz"}`, I have `{name: "ijk", place: "uvx"}`. How can I avoid data getting multiplied on each page refresh?

Comment: @Palvo I guess localstorage is part of HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into `a` before inserting new data.

```
if (!a.some(filterData(data)) {
  a.push(data);
}

function filterData(data) {
  return function(item) {
    return item.name === data.name && item.place === data.place;
  };
}
```

You could achieve the same thing with a loop:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = a.length; i--;) {
  if (a[i].name === data.name && a[i].place === data.place) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  a.push(data);
}
```